# WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of null

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, graphql, gatsby

I'm just a newbie to programming and have just tried GatsbyJs for a few months. I ran the command "gatsby build", this is the error that comes up, It works fine on "gatsby develop".

```
1:24:14 AM: failed Building static HTML for pages - 12.853s
1:24:14 AM: error Building static HTML failed for path "/products/"
1:24:14 AM: 
1:24:14 AM:   101 | 
1:24:14 AM:   102 |     var _useReduxContext = useReduxContext(),
1:24:14 AM: > 103 |         store = _useReduxContext.store,
1:24:14 AM:       | ^
1:24:14 AM:   104 |         contextSub = _useReduxContext.subscription;
1:24:14 AM:   105 | 
1:24:14 AM:   106 |     var selectedState = useSelectorWithStoreAndSubscription(selector, equalityFn, store, contextSub);
1:24:14 AM: 
1:24:14 AM:   WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of null
1:24:14 AM:   
1:24:14 AM:   - useSelector.js:103 
1:24:14 AM:     node_modules/react-redux/es/hooks/useSelector.js:103:1
1:24:14 AM:   
1:24:14 AM:   - index.js:12 
1:24:14 AM:     src/components/ProductListing/index.js:12:37
1:24:14 AM:   
1:24:14 AM: 
1:24:14 AM: not finished Generating image thumbnails - 85.375s
1:24:14 AM: ​
1:24:14 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
1:24:14 AM:   "build.command" failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a huge lack of details and configurations (`gatsby-ssr.js`, `gatsby-browser.js`, etc). However, I think your issue is quite similar to [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/6362). So:

- If you are using `gatsby-ssr.js` APIs (specifically `replaceRenderer`). Try changing:

  ```
    exports.replaceRenderer
  ```

  To:

  ```
  export const replaceRenderer
  ```
- Remove the `connect` importation (from Redux) in your code. This should be avoided if not used:

  ```
  import { connect } from 'react-redux'
  ```